# Problems installing development package from either GitHub or local

Tags: r, installation

I've been corresponding with the package author about an error I'm getting in the `HLMdiag` package. He suggested that I install the development version [https://github.com/aloy/HLMdiag]. So, I'm trying to install the development version from both GitHub and a local version that he sent me. I'm running into errors for both my work computer and personal computer. I'm hoping someone in the user community who is more knowledgeable about such things can help solve this.

My initial thought was that there might be some security protocol on my work machine that was causing problems, which is why I attempted the install on a personal machine. I **am** getting different error messages on the different machines; but still unable to install on either. Any help would be very much appreciated.

*Sorry in advance for the post length. I wanted to give as much of the error messages / log as possible.*

**Machine 1 -- personal**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] devtools_1.6.1 tools_3.1.2
```

**Attempt (A) - direct from GitHub**

```
devtools::install_github("aloy/HLMdiag")
Downloading github repo aloy/HLMdiag@master
Installing HLMdiag
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\crossfit_al1985\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8o4p3s\devtools24b871ace19\aloy-HLMdiag-3f7977d"  \
  --library="C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: cooksd_obs.o: File format not recognized
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: cooksd_subset.o: File format not recognized
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: covratio.o: File format not recognized
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: covtrace.o: File format not recognized
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: linear_algebra_fnc.o: File format not recognized
C:\RBuildTools\3.1\gcc-4.6.3\bin\nm.exe: mdffits_subset.o: File format not recognized
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o HLMdiag.dll tmp.def cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
cooksd_obs.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

**Attempt (B) - via `install.packages()` from local**

```
setwd(...)
install.packages("./HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_obs.cpp -o cooksd_obs.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_subset.cpp -o cooksd_subset.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covratio.cpp -o covratio.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covtrace.cpp -o covtrace.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c linear_algebra_fnc.cpp -o linear_algebra_fnc.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c mdffits_subset.cpp -o mdffits_subset.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o HLMdiag.dll tmp.def cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_obs.cpp -o cooksd_obs.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_subset.cpp -o cooksd_subset.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covratio.cpp -o covratio.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covtrace.cpp -o covtrace.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c linear_algebra_fnc.cpp -o linear_algebra_fnc.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c mdffits_subset.cpp -o mdffits_subset.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o HLMdiag.dll tmp.def cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag/libs/x64
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function from function 'adjust_lmList' in package 'HLMdiag'
Error in setMethod("lmList", signature(formula = "formula", data = "data.frame"),  : 
  no existing definition for function 'lmList'
Error : unable to load R code in package 'HLMdiag'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\crossfit_al1985\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "./HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘./HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Attempt (C) - via unzipping and `devtools::install()`**

```
setwd(...)
devtools::install("HLMdiag")
Installing HLMdiag
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\crossfit_al1985\Downloads\HLMdiag"  \
  --library="C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_obs.cpp -o cooksd_obs.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_subset.cpp -o cooksd_subset.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covratio.cpp -o covratio.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covtrace.cpp -o covtrace.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c linear_algebra_fnc.cpp -o linear_algebra_fnc.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c mdffits_subset.cpp -o mdffits_subset.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o HLMdiag.dll tmp.def cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_obs.cpp -o cooksd_obs.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c cooksd_subset.cpp -o cooksd_subset.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covratio.cpp -o covratio.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c covtrace.cpp -o covtrace.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c linear_algebra_fnc.cpp -o linear_algebra_fnc.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c mdffits_subset.cpp -o mdffits_subset.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o HLMdiag.dll tmp.def cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag/libs/x64
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function from function 'adjust_lmList' in package 'HLMdiag'
Error in setMethod("lmList", signature(formula = "formula", data = "data.frame"),  : 
  no existing definition for function 'lmList'
Error : unable to load R code in package 'HLMdiag'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/crossfit_al1985/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

**Machine 2 -- work**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.4    evaluate_0.5.5  formatR_0.10    htmltools_0.2.4 httr_0.6.1      knitr_1.6      
 [7] memoise_0.2.1   parallel_3.1.1  RCurl_1.95-4.1  rmarkdown_0.4.2 stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.1    
[13] whisker_0.3-2
```

**Attempt (A) -- direct from github**

```
devtools::install_github("aloy/HLMdiag")
Installing github repo HLMdiag/master from aloy
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/aloy/HLMdiag/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\alewit\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpATVjSy/master.zip
Installing HLMdiag
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\alewit\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpATVjSy\devtoolsc745bf04fbd\HLMdiag-master"  \
  --library="C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="HLMdiag.dll" OBJECTS="cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

**Attempt (B) -- via `install.packages()` from local**

```
setwd(...)
install.packages("./HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="HLMdiag.dll" OBJECTS="cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\alewit\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "C:/Users/alewit/Downloads/HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/alewit/Downloads/HLMdiag_0.3.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Attempt (C) -- via `devtools::install()`**

```
setwd(...)
install("HLMdiag")
Installing HLMdiag
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL "C:\Users\alewit\Downloads\HLMdiag"  \
  --library="C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'HLMdiag' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="HLMdiag.dll" OBJECTS="cooksd_obs.o cooksd_subset.o covratio.o covtrace.o linear_algebra_fnc.o mdffits_subset.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'HLMdiag'
* removing 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/alewit/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/HLMdiag'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: Are you able to install any other packages that need compilation on your work machine?  It looks to be an issue with the compiling step.

Comment: Do you have Rtools installed?

Comment: I updated to R 3.1.2 (from 3.1.1) and installed Rtools. I tried installing make 4.1; but seem to have had some issues. I tried installing lme4 from GitHub and got this error `Warning in cleanup_pkg(pkgdir, Log) :
  unable to run 'make clean' in 'src'`

Comment: It's an issue with your Rtools installation.  Even though you installed it are you sure Rtools is on your PATH?  My guess is that it isn't. Rtools doesn't modify the path by default unless you check a certain checkbox during installation.  That checkbox is also usually terrible because it outputs your full path and makes the entire thing readable so I've known a few people that just go "wtf is this" and skip over that part and are then confused why Rtools doens't seem to be doing anything. tldr; check your path and see if Rtools is on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .o files in the src directory were messing things up.  I submitted a pull request so hopefully Adam will incorporate those fixes soon and your problem *should* go away.  You could test if this works by using

```
install_github("Dasonk/HLMdiag")
```

until the pull request is accepted.

Edit: And Adam was quick to merge.  Test out installing from github again `install_github("aloy/HLMdiag")` and it should work for you.

Comment: Adam just emailed me the update to the Github version. The install from GitHub is now working on my local but still not on my work computer. I'll have to talk to IT today or tomorrow and get that sorted out.... Thanks!

Comment: Is it generally true that `*.o` files cause trouble? I am seeing the same error `...uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o"' had status 127` for `data.table` at the moment. If not, I'll post my own question.

Comment: @Frank I tend to also have problems with `*.o` files. Often a call to  `devtools::compile_dll(...)` will resolve things (or partially resolve)